# print escaped subprocess.run string when called with list

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using python's subprocess module to do a system call.
I am passing a list to subprocess.run so that subprocess will handle escaping my arguments.

```py
    result = subprocess.run([
        'curl',
        '--form', 'measurement=river_discharge',
        '--form', 'file=@/my/file/path',
        'http://my_server.com/webform'
    ], check=True)
```

I want to print the escaped string from subprocess so that I can copy-paste it.
`result.args` after running the command is the same list I submitted.
Is there a way to get the escaped string subprocess generates from this list?

In my example the string I am looking for would be something like

```
curl 
--form measurement=river_discharge 
--form file=@/my/file/path 
http://my_server.com/webform
```

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess` doesn't actually generate an escaped string. Each element of the list is simply passed as a separate argument when executing the command. There's no shell involved, so no need to escape anything.

However, you can use [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to emulate the necessary quoting.

```
import shlex

print(' '.join(map(shlex.quote, result.args)))
```